# What does this require() statement mean?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am looking at the code example in https://github.com/mjhea0/passport-local-express4

I encountered this require() statement.

```
app.use(require('morgan')('combined'));
```

All the other `require` statements I have used looks something like `var XXX = require('module_name');`

What does `app.use(require('morgan')('combined'));` mean? Load both 'morgan' and 'combined' modules?

Comment: `morgan` is exporting a **function** that accepts a parameter, `require('morgan')('combined')` is calling the exported function with the parameter.

Comment: Thanks. Why not you put it as an answer? I can upvote it that way.

Comment: Note that exports objects are cached and reused.  https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/getting-started/what-is-require

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better practice to declare your dependencies all in one place. You can do something like this:

```
var morgan = require('morgan');

...

app.use(morgan('combined')) /* combined is added as a parameter of morgan */
```

Makes your codebase easier to maintain.

See docs here: https://github.com/expressjs/morgan

Answer (score 1):

This implies that you are:-
Create a new morgan logger middleware function using the given format (Combined)

You can also do the same as follows:-

```
var express = require('express')
var morgan = require('morgan')
var app = express()
app.use(morgan('combined'))
```